# was trying to borrow some money from you, wasn’t he?

Tags: tag-questions

What is the difference in meaning between the following sentences, if both are said with a rising intonation at the end?

> a. John was trying to borrow some money from you, wasn’t he?

> b. John wasn't trying to borrow some money from you, was he?

Comment: On is negative and one is declarative. The tags are for spoken language. The intonation makes no difference.

Comment: The first version is a *rhetorical question*. The speaker *probably already believes* John wanted to borrow money (which speaker disapproves of). And speaker believes the addressee *also* doesn't approve of Johns borrowing habits, so it's implicit in the rhetorical question that addressee *didn't lend John any money* (the "expected" reply being "Yeah, but I didn't give him any"). The second version *also* implies disapproval of John trying to borrow money, but the implication is that would be a very bad thing, and speaker hopes addressee will confirm that the bad thing ***didn't*** happen.

Answer (score 3):

> John **was** trying..., **wasn't** he?

This is the standard or basic version of the question. It is neutral. The person asking believes the answer is going to be "yes, he was."

It could be used when the questioner doesn't remember the situation (either John's actions or whether or not it was John doing the action, depending on the emphasis).

> John **wasn't** trying..., **was** he?

The inversion carries a more negative tone. There are two possibilities: the person asking believes the answer is going to be "no," *or* they believe the answer is going to be "yes" and they disapprove of that.